# Clear form input is also clearing buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to clear a `form`:

```
$('#signup_form').find('input').not(':button').val('');
```

but it is also clearing the `buttons` values.

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: You can try using $('#signup_form').find('input[type="text"]')

Comment: `$('#signup_form input').not('[type="button"]').val('')`

Comment: Your code seems to work fine. May be we are missing something here. Could you please post a functional example that illustrates your problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your button is of type="submit"?

Try this:

```
$('#signup_form').find('input').not(':button,:submit').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#signup_form').find('textarea,input[type=text]').each(function() {
    $(this).val('');
});
```

Where in `#signup_form` is your form.This will clear all the input in your form

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `not` filter like below:

```
$('#signup_form input').not(':button,:submit').val('');
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vywcp5c0/2/)